# I'm unable to display fontawesome icons in my vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

In my **main.js** I have:

```js
    import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
    import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    import { faFontAwesome } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

    library.add(faUserSecret)
    library.add(faFontAwesome)


    Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

In my **component** I have

```html
     <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fa', 'fa-search']" />
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'user-secret']" />
     </button>
```

And I only see the second icon...what am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of:

`<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fa', 'fa-search']" />`

it should be:

`<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fa', 'search']" />`